# How to change SOA Record in Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, godaddy, dns-zone

We have changed our NS records (from Godaddy to AWS) about 48h ago in Godaddy.

The NS records have changed, but the SOA record is still pointing the old Godaddy NS.

How can i change it?

; SOA Record --> HOW CAN I CHANGE IT?

```
somedomain.com. 3600    IN  SOA ns05.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net (
                2013092502
                28800
                7200
                604800
                3600
)
```

; NS Records --> THIS IS OK.

```
@   3600    IN  NS  ns-378.awsdns-47.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns-672.awsdns-20.net
```

Comment: What tool did you use to generate the output shown in your question and how did you invoke it?

Comment: The Godaddy DNS export tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move your domain DNS from GoDaddy to AWS, you will need to get your domain updated with the registrar your domain is registered with.

When you registered the domain you may have noticed that you have to provide 2 or more nameservers for it. This is basically what you are paying for - the registrar will get those nameservers added to the global DNS servers for whichever TLD your domain comes under.

You don't need to change the SOA record (or any of the actual DNS records for that matter). If you've got DNS set up with AWS already, then the DNS settings at AWS will already have all the correct SOA/NS records. You just need to get your domain updated so that the .com DNS servers send requests for your domain to Amazon instead of GoDaddy.